# How to convert C# InnerText XPath method in Java?

Tags: c#, java, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I have the following **C#** method that contains an **XPath** query:

```
  public bool setDriveParameter(DefaultDriveParameter parameter, string valore){
      System.Xml.XmlNode n;
      n = _document.SelectSingleNode("//root/settings/defaults/" + parameter.ToString().Replace("_", "-"));
      if (n == null) {
          return false;
      }

      n.InnerText = valore;

      return true;
  }
```

and I have to convert it in **Java** but I have a doubt related the XPath query, I have do something like this:

```
  public boolean setDriveParameter(DefaultDriveParameter parameter, String valore) {
      Element n;
      XPath xPath;

      try {
          xPath = XPath.newInstance("//root/settings/defaults/" + parameter.toString().replace("_", "-") );
          n = (Element) xPath.selectSingleNode(CONFIG_DOCUMENT);

          if (n == null) {
              return false;
          }
          n.setText(valore);

      } catch (JDOMException e) {
      }
      return true;

  }
```

My doubt is mainly related to this C# line:

```
 n.InnerText = valore;
```

in Java is correct use:

```
n.setText(valore);
```

have the same meaning?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not so much a question of Java versus C# but rather of the API you use. Assuming you use JDOM http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/Element.html#setText%28java.lang.String%29 with Java then yes, the call `n.setText(valore)` is equivalent to C# and XmlElement/XmlNode (the DOM API in the .NET framework) and `n.InnerText = valore`.